# Same view for multiple models in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have several models for different categories like Laptops,Mobiles,Softwares,Clothing etc.
Each of these classes have their own attributes.I have one view to display the list of categories but different action methods like

```
public ActionResult Mobiles()
        {
            var q = from n in db.Mobiles
                    select n;
            return View(q);
        }
  public ActionResult Laptops()
        {
            var q = from n in db.Laptops
                    select n;
            return View(q);
       }
```

Should I make different views for different action results or need only one to render all.

Need help

Comment: If you want one view then create a view model otherwise create seperate views

Comment: share your models . that would be helpful  .

Comment: Mobiles attributes may include like name,OS,Sim,CPU,RAM,ROM,Size,Dsiplay,Network,GPS,GPRS,WAP/MMS,WLAN,Bluetooth,camera etc etc similar for laptop they have their own , Clothing also differs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the properties you want to display are common between your models, like `category` and `name` then you may use the same `View` and not declare a specific `Model` for it.

If all your models share a common `Interface` and you only want to show properties defined on those `Interfaces` then you could declare your the `Model` in your `View` to be the `Interface`.

For instance:

```
public Interface IProduct
{
    string Category {get;set;}
    string Name {get;set;}
}

public class Laptop : IProduct
{
    public string Category {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public bool HasBluRay {get;set;}
}

public class Mobile :IProduct
{
    public string Category {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public bool externalRAMSlot {get;set;}
}
```

Now if you only care to list `Category` and `Name` of your products, then you could have this view:

```
@model IEnumerable<IProduct>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Product Name </th>
    </tr>
    @for(var product in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>@product.Category</td>
        <td>@product.Name</td>
    </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: Can you explain the second point with little code i have different properties for different categories

Comment: @user3814490 Check it out now.

Comment: I think this will be better to make a common interface.

Answer (score 0):

You have to **take different Views** for displaying details of different categories like

Laptops,Mobiles,Softwares,Clothing etc because as you are saying that you have different model

classes for each category so in MVC for **one view** you can take a **single model class** so

different Views will suit your requirement otherwise you have to make one `viewmodel` for all categories.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have some kind of "generic viewmodel" in a view. What are the attributes that differs?

If they are pretty much the same you could have the same viewmodel for all your categories and have some kind of conditions in your view. Like:

class="@(Model.IsLaptop ? "something" : "")

The other solution could be to have the common properties in an interface and use a partial view for those in your view. You would then have to use several views but with minimal markup in them.